# Converting DES encryption to RSA encryption

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, des

I have an Encyption Part in my C# program that is encrypted with DES encryption. It just encrypts "005". I want this part but with RSA encryption.I don't know how to use C# codes.Can anyone help me

```
/*********************Message Encryption******************************/
string smsg = "005";
string venc;
DESCryptoServiceProvider iDESCryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
System.Text.Encoding iEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] vkey = iEncoding.GetBytes("12345678");
byte[] viv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
ICryptoTransform iICryptoTransform = iDESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(vkey, viv);
byte[] vmsg = iEncoding.GetBytes(smsg);
byte[] benc = iICryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(vmsg, 0, vmsg.Length);
venc = System.Convert.ToBase64String(benc);
/****************Message Encryption******************************/
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. DES and RSA have completely different purposes. You use RSA if you need it's asymmetric properties. You don't use it to encrypt with a shared key. If you want a modern replacement for DES, use AES.

Comment: A constant `IV` is useless too, and your scheme lacks authentication.

Comment: Maybe you might want to tell us what you want to achieve by encryption, you might get better answers.

Comment: Thank you very much...
But my problem is that I don't know much about encryption and I'm a freshman.Actually I had found a ready program and I wanted to change it because I don't want it to be a copied one. I've changed other parts of the program but about this part because I don't Know encryption well I couldn't change it. I just want to change it! CHANGE is my only goal. And I just want to change it and encrypt it with another encryption method except DES

Comment: @CodeInChaos although what you are saying is correct, RSA can be used for encryption. Granted, a lot of properties differ significantly from symmetric ciphers, but you end up with valid ciphertext nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a cryptography task.

Anyway, what you need to do is to swap DESCryptoServiceProvider for RSACryptoServiceProvider. Additionally, as RSA is a PKI cipher while DES is a symmetric block cipher, you will need to create appropriate parameters and so on. So the actual encryption will be also done using different keys, if that was one of your goals to achieve.

Finally, all the necessary code can be found at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx

**EDIT**

Ok, so from what I gather from your responses, You don't actually want to use RSA. Just any other cipher, right?

In that case, what you can choose from, assuming you want to keep .NET' `System.Security.Crytography` library as your source, you can choose from 4 symmetric encryption (read the same type of) algorithms. These are:

- [AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx)
- [DES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.descryptoserviceprovider.aspx)
- [RC2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rc2cryptoserviceprovider.aspx)
- [TripleDES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

They have all very similar interface, so just choose one of them (my advice is to pick AES) and rework your code. They have identical interfaces (if I didn't miss something from the quick look), so all you would really need to do is to replace all occurrences of DES with AES. As simple as that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much...
But my problem is that I don't know much about encryption and I'm a freshman.Actually I had found a ready program and I wanted to change it because I don't want it to be a copied one. I've changed other parts of the program but about this part because I don't Know encryption well I couldn't change it. I just want to change it! CHANGE is my only goal. And I just want to change it and encrypt it with another encryption method except DES

Comment: Actually I checked Microsoft site too. But when I use it's method, my program will face a lot of errors and because I don't know encryption well I can't fix those errors

Comment: Thank You very much...yes You are right I just want to use any other cipher except DES. Thank you for your guide. I replaced them with AES but it didn't work because I think there are some differences between them and for AES we should use  "using" before "AesCryptoServiceProvider" and there were some errors in the program. I used TripleDES it didn't have any errors but the program didn't work

Comment: Sorry can I ask another question?
I'd Like to Know the advantages of Triple DES over DES
Is there any advantages?

Comment: Well, basically it's just a little bit better over DES with regard to the brute-force attack. That depends mostly on the keying options. See `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES` for some simple overview.